# Unit test stopped working when switching from Karma to Jest

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, jestjs

I am working on an Ionic/Angular project and tried switching from Karma to Jest for my testing. 
The following test was running fine before the switch:

```
import {TestBed, inject, async} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TreasureTableService } from './treasure-table.service';
import {PapaParseModule} from 'ngx-papaparse';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

describe('TreasureTableService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule, PapaParseModule]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject([TreasureTableService], s => {
    treasureTableService = s;
  }));

  it('should get treasure type list', async() => {
    let result: string[] = await treasureTableService.getTreasureTypeList();
    expect(result).toContain("A");
    expect(result.length).toBe(33);
  });
});
```

After I switched to Jest I got the following error:

```
    console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
    Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
  at Object.dispatchError (C:\Users\fhu\WebstormProjects\AcksAssistant\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr-utils.js:65:19)
        at Request.client.on.err (C:\Users\fhu\WebstormProjects\AcksAssistant\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xmlhttprequest.js:676:20)
        at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
        at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
        at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\fhu\WebstormProjects\AcksAssistant\node_modules\request\request.js:881:8)
        at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
        at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
```

Anyone got an idea what the problem could be?

EDIT:
After I stopped using the `HttpClientModule` and switched to the `HttpClientTestingModule` the connection Error went away but now I have problem with the async call:

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
95 | function createdPatchedSpec(OriginalSpec, registry) {
96 |   function PatchedSpec(attrs) {
>  97 |     OriginalSpec.apply(this, arguments);
```

Comment: For the note: There are Jest test that are running just fine so I think its not just a configuration problem.

Comment: How could it work with karma? It seems that your test is doing http request to localhost. Did your localhost run when you ran your karma test?

Comment: Yes, Karma did open a browser window. I thought that one of big advantages with Jest is that they can do it without an open browser by probably doing it in a headless chrome in the background.

Comment: Actually jest doesn't run in any browser, it currently runs only in `jsdom`. My question was whether your dev server with your app was running when you ran your karma tests or not.

Comment: I see! I dont recall that I had to start the dev server beforehand, never noticed any problems once the test was running correctly.

Comment: Hm, strange. Could you inspect how your karma test managed to correctly call the http request and trace it down? Nevertheless, your test should not do any xhr requests to any server at all. You should use `HttpClientTestingModule` and mock all request in your tests.

Comment: Sure, I could rollback and test it but what tool could I use to capture the http request? I dont think I have seen an option in my IDE (WebStorm) for something like that... Maybe Wireshark? Thanks for the hint with `HttpClientTestingModule`! I will add it to my question.

Comment: I personally use fiddler from telerik, it's free tool and you can intercept all requests. Or you can debug your test and see what is happening, for example in `HttpClient`. Or you can check the network tab in chrome dev tools when your tests run.